# How to generate scaffold into a table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm just learning about Ruby on rails, how to generate scaffold into a table. I try to create contacts database with name:string phone:string email:string, rails gives me this view instead of table view [this view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MXyAQ.png). Thank you